# Suggested edit doesn't seem to edit anything

Tags: support, bug, suggested-edits

How was an anonymous user able to suggest [this edit](https://meta.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/71843)? (**Warning**: it has an offensive edit summary, which has been edited out in the screenshot below.) It doesn't seem to change anything, not even when viewing the Markdown source:

[image]

IIRC, if you suggest an edit and then immediately edit it again, but if the new edit doesn't meet the 6 character minimum it won't be accepted by the system. I just tried (while logged out) to retag this question and undo that in the grace period, but I get a message ['Nothing appears to have changed'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b04Qe.png), as it should.

Comment: Isn't it possible to add 6 chars to meet the requirement and the remove those 6 chars again (which then also meets the requirement). The net result is that nothing has been changed in the suggested edit.

Comment: No, the submitted content is (AFAIK) always checked against the latest revision. I've had multiple times where I re-submitted a (valid) suggested edit where I spotted another typo after submitting a first attempt.

Comment: Hmm, it seems you can use empty Unicode characters to (sort of) propose an empty edit: http://emptycharacter.com. By the way, I wonder who tried to edit the question .

Comment: @Zera If that user of the other user really used empty characters, then the result is different. SE detects a change and tries to show them. The first edit is identified as "identical versions"

Comment: @Tom That is why I said *sort of*.

Comment: I got a similarly weird edit by Samuel Liew on my answer [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/346767/revisions) (look at the side by side markdown.) Related?

Comment: @Spevacus maybe, but since Samuel has edit privileges, he can edit and undo his edit without being limited by the 6 character rule (I just tested this). There are similar cases for using the rollback function during the grace period.

Comment: Well I just tried to edit in a hello and it didn’t reproduce this bug. The hello shows up, surprisingly. Also it is nigh impossible to review edits on a phone.

Comment: What if they entered something that gets stripped out to protect against bad input? There could be a bug if there is a difference in timing between the code that tests for character changes and the code that renders the differences.

Comment: Here's another one: https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/30021807