# Empty suggested edit by an anonymous user

Tags: support, suggested-edits, character-limit, anonymous

I just got an [empty suggested edit](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/21090) by an anonymous user in the "Suggested edits" review queue:
[image: empty suggested edit]

The edit shows no change in the Markdown or in the rendered output of the post. This can also be seen in the [revision history](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/posts/13482/revisions) (Revision 6).

The suggested edit did have a very long comment, so it was not an automatic edit. I approved the edit because it really does not make a difference in this case whether it gets approved or rejected (no change in the post, no user whose edit history and reputation can be updated).

How did this anonymous user get around the [6-character limit](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/76251/643262) for suggested edits?

Comment: Possibly related? https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/347198/suggested-edit-doesnt-seem-to-edit-anything

Comment: If the edit made no (observable) changes, let alone good ones, it should have been rejected.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Suggested edit doesn't seem to edit anything](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/347198/suggested-edit-doesnt-seem-to-edit-anything) (Except that it doesn't have an answer.)

Comment: The duplicate doesn't answer the question. It has zero answers and some wild guesses in comments.